# Find number of spaces in a string in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

What method do I call to find the number of spaces in a string in Swift? I want to loop through that number, something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stack: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var plus: UIButton!

 @IBAction func sum(sender: AnyObject) {
    var stackTitle = stack.text
    var numberOfSpaces = stackTitle!.CanICallSomethingHereToHelp:)
    var i:Int
    for i = 1; i < numberOfSpaces; ++i{
        operate(plus)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Swift 5 or later**

In Swift 5 we can use the new Character properties [isWhitespace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127019-iswhitespace) and [isNewline](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127014-isnewline)

```
let str = "Hello, playground. Hello, playground !!!"
let spaceCount = str.reduce(0) { $1.isWhitespace && !$1.isNewline ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
print(spaceCount) // 4
```

---

If your intent is to count `" "` only

```
let spaceCount = str.reduce(0) { $1 == " " ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```

Comment: As of Swift 2, use Array(str.characters)

Comment: Using `isWhitespace` is incorrect for counting spaces. `isWhitespace` includes newlines, tabs, and paragraph separators, so you could end up with more "spaces" than expected.

Comment: @JoshCorreia I wonder why it is not mentioned on documentation

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation of isWhitespace that you linked. Go to the "Discussion" section. The Swift 4 implementation that you list works in Swift 5 as well and I think it's the only acceptable answer. Your edit to your post still won't work for tabs or paragraph separators.

Comment: Read the first line on the page, "A Boolean value indicating whether this character represents whitespace, including newlines."

Comment: That’s true but it is not listed below

Comment: The Discussion section only shows examples and unfortunately does not include a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 3):

```
let title = "A sample string to test with."
let count = title.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").count - 1
print(count) // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be the implementation of the following function :

```
func nbSpacesIn(_ word: String) -> Int {
return String(word.unicodeScalars.filter({$0.value == 32})).count}
```