# Swift - Whitespace count in a string

Tags: ios, swift

How do you get the count of the empty space within text?

It would be more helpful to me if explained with an example.

Comment: Already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993208/find-number-of-spaces-in-a-string-in-swift

Comment: The question that this is marked as a duplicate of answers how to count the spaces in a string, but that does not account for characters such as tabs or newlines. This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to consider other whitespace characters (not only <kbd>space</kbd>) use regular expression:

```
let string = "How to get count of the empty space in text,Like how we get character count like wise i need empty space count in a text, It would be more helpful if explained with an example."

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s")
let numberOfWhitespaceCharacters = regex.numberOfMatches(in: string, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
```

Regular expression `\\s` considers <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>cr</kbd>, <kbd>lf</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: if I want to find count for both space and new line then what will be the expression?

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `componentsSeparatedBy` or `filter` function like

```
let array = string.components(separatedBy:" ")
let spaceCount = array.count - 1
```

or

```
let spaceCount = string.filter{$0 == " "}.count
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to do something like this:

```
let emptySpacesCount = yourString.characters.filter { $0 == " " }.count
```

What this does is it takes characters from your string, filter out everything that is not <kbd>space</kbd> and then counts number of remaining elements.

Comment: That will only work for the space character, not for other white space characters.

Comment: I know, question did say space, it's not exactly clear on what OP actually wants

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example;

```swift
    let string = "Whitespace count in a string swift"
    let spaceCount = string.characters.filter{$0 == " "}.count
```